# How send content body in Http Request with GET method in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, .net-core, .net-4.8

I need to do a HTTP Request from .Net with method GET and send the data in content body. I would like to do with this .Net Framework and if not posible with .Net Core.

I have try with RestSharp library but return the following error  "Http verb GET does not support body", and with webClient return also an error ("Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.").

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Various options.  The ````HttpClient```` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0.  You can use the ````GetAsync()```` to read it async or use the ````GetAsync().Result```` to read it non-async as a ````HttpResponseMessage````

Comment: Use `Post` instead of `Get`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-5.0